# Objective C Nested Dictionary Access Invalid Selector Error

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I am new to Objective C and I am trying to parse a dictionary representation of the Geocoding API JSON response. Here is what I've got:

```
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];
NSDictionary *results = [responseDict objectForKey:@"results"];
NSDictionary *geometry = [results objectForKey:@"geometry"];
```

I receive a SIGABRT error indicating an invalid selector. I do not know how to remedy this or maybe even better, is there another way of doing nested dictionary access?

You can see the json response here:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true

**EDIT:** added more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you need to see what responseDict is.  It is very possibly nil. You need to determine what value is coming back from [responseString JSONValue] (it could be either an NSDictionary or NSArray - but SBJSON could also return nil for this).

In short, I can pretty much guarantee that responseDict is not an NSDictionary instance.

Comment: I was able to display the contents of the results variable in the debugger and it shows the corresponding data from the JSON response. The error occurs on that line where I try to pass an objectForKey message to the results variable

Comment: Can you verify that the results variable is an NSDictionary and not an NSArray instance?

Comment: now that, is probably what I need to do and the answer I need to this question and I don't know how to do that

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the 4th line of your code above.  The debugger will give you the type information.  Also, don't set the type of results to NSDictionary, but instead type it as id (which can be any object instance).  If you can't see the type information in the debugger, you can always type:

    po [results class]

Comment: If it was `nil` it would do nothing, not cause a crash.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the class of the object returned by `-objectForKey:`. `-objectForKey:` returns an `id` which you are assuming to be an `NSDictionary` unfortunately for you in the response you get back "results" will return an array which your JSON parser is likely to return as an `NSArray` which does not respond to `-objectForKey:`.